# How do I trace my inner pages via google analytics?

Tags: javascript, css, google-analytics

I am making a website with HTML and CSS, and it'll be having like around 200 inner pages inside. How can I track them via google analytics? Am I supposed to add the tracking code to every page, Or just adding it to the homepage is enough?

IF, I am supposed to add the code to every page, should I make a new property for every inner page in google analytics?

Comment: You just need to add the code to every page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the GA code to every page. If you are writing your website with some kind of server side, than I suggest you write a kind of MasterPage / Common code that run on every page that all your pages will use and that will be injecting that js code to the pages.

That is good practice in any case - especially if you have so many pages. what if you would like to change the design of the site? or add a common header/footer to all pages? you would go over and edit 200 pages? that way you only need to change one place.

Comment: Hey, thanks firstly. My plan is to make a website, that'll be selling web templates. So, I don't think there'll be any header and footer master code.

Comment: They don't need to have the same look, or even visual html elements. just shared code.

Comment: So shall i add the same code to all of them? Or shall i make a separate code for each one of them?

Comment: same code. it's the code you get from google when you register a site to analytics.

Comment: Cool. I'll get, the statistics for each and every page theb right?

Comment: No. One code. The js code from google knows what page in the site the visitor is on automatically and reports it to their servers.

Comment: Thank you for your patience. The thing that is confusing me, is with the same code, how'll google let me know of each page? I've used it once for a WordPress website. And it shows me only one statistic and not of each page.

Comment: What they actually do in their javascript script is getting the current url the script is running on. It's a very simple thing to do: http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_window_location.asp

Comment: Woah! Crazy. Thank you very much buddy.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you'll want to find a way to add the google analytics tracking .js to every page.

Generally, this is done via a template: you want to have every page have the same look-and-feel, with the same navigation links, right?

Assuming each of those 200 pages has a different URL, you do not need to add additional categorization - you can use the URLs to track the individual pages.  Ideally, you'll have some sort of hierarchical URL structure; you can then use parts of the URLs to track various groups of pages in Google Analytics.

Comment: Thanks. No, they will not be having the same look. I am making a website that'll be selling web templates. So, I just need to make a website of mine, and the inner pages will be showing the demos of templates. And yes, they will be hierarchical. 

So now, I should add a new property in GA settings and get a new code for each and every page?

Comment: If you're selling templates, I'd definitely recommend a 'master' template with analytics code and other fundamental includes that you'll be using on each page.  For example, if you use ZURB Foundation to build your templates, then you'll want to include some foundational CSS in your 'master' template, which you'll extend on each of your pages.  If you're selling templates, then use your single code for the sales site, and use a different code if/when you sell a template and implement it in a new site.

Comment: Thanks again. But it's a simple website. Which will redirect to my email and paypal for the dealing. So, in this case, what should I do? Add code to every page? If yes, will it be the same code? Or should I generate a new one for each page?